# How create input with a double white bottom-border?

Tags: html, css

[image]

hi all, help me please to create input with border and double white border on bottom...
that's my css & html, thanks brahs )

```
    <input type="text" id="inputName" name="name">
body {background:#F1EFEB; }
input{
      border: 1px solid #CFC8BC;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to use the vertical-offset of the [`box-shadow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow) property

```
input {
border: 1px solid #CFC8BC;
border-radius: 4px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 01px #CFC8BC;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 01px #CFC8BC;
box-shadow: 0 01px #CFC8BC;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZSN4/

You can alternatively include the `inset` keyword and use a negative vertical-offset:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZSN4/1/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `border-bottom: 3px double white` works.  I've only checked in Firefox and Chrome, though.

Of course, you'll have to change the background color of your `input` to see the white border.

http://jsfiddle.net/ghodmode/MPt7Y/

Comment: @DimitriBadicean, it creates double white border as requested in the question. It seems that you meant to ask something else.